# `window.location.href` does not work on react app when deploying on github pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

There is a similar sounding question but my problem is different.

While running the `react` app on localhost it navigates from the following page,

[image]

The submit button has the code `window.location.href = "/ahana-psychometry/assessments/";`
And so it navigates to the page:

[image]

But when I press on the submit button on the page at gh-pages, the url changes from `blenderous.github.io/ahana-psychometry/create` to `blenderous.github.io/ahana-psychometry/assessments/`. but

[image]

but the page displays the 404 message instead:

[image]

Comment: Are you using react-router? It's confusing. In the first image, it's localhost why should it go to "blenderous.github.io"???

Comment: Yes, I am using react-router. In the first two images, it's localhost and it's working fine. In the third and fourth images, it's blenderous.github.io where it shows a 404 when clicked on the submit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using react router, the best way is using its methods.

Here is an example, which describes using withRouter HOC to redirect to another page:

```
import {
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'

class Sample extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    ...
    this.props.history.push('/ahana-psychometry/')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Sample)
```

Comment: How can it be done if the redirect should go to an entirely different domain?

Comment: @GaganTK Just give it the absolute URL: `this.props.history.push('/ahana-psychometry/')` => `this.props.history.push('https://example.com/ahana-psychometry/')`

Comment: @alizera When I do that, the URL gets appended to existing path and does not get redirected to it

Comment: @GaganTK So use `replace` instead of `push`.